# Unity : Issues in using Raycast method to detect the player position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project in Unity in which I need to know the position of the player, whether the player is standing on the platform or the ground. The player can teleport between these two. I have written this code that works most of the time, except that at certain times, it returns the incorrect response. This happens specially when I have either teleported from the ground to platform or vice versa or if I am standing almost at the edge of the platform. Could someone please suggest how to handle this?

```
private float distance = 0.5f;
void Update(){
        RaycastHit hit;

        Ray footstepRay = new Ray (transform.position, Vector3.down);
        if(Physics.Raycast(footstepRay, out hit, distance)){
            if(hit.collider.tag == "Ground"){
                Debug.Log ("Player is standing on the ground");
            }
            else if(hit.collider.tag == "Platform"){
                Debug.Log ("Player is standing on the platform");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Vector3.down is local or absolute position?

Comment: It should be absolute position, its not relative to any gameobject. Does that answer your question, kindly elaborate in case you feel I have not understood your question well.

Comment: That was exactly what I was asking, just to corroborate that the problem was not raycast orientation. Try to print on debug the "hit.collider.gameObject.name" to know which "thing" are you hitting. Maybe you got some other "invisible" collider affecting it (it happens to me EVERY single time ^^)

Comment: does incorrect response mean 'platform' instead of 'ground', or does it mean that the hit is not detected?

Comment: Are you sure that the raycast is not hitting your player object itself? Try using Debug.Log(hit.collider) before the second if statement to see what you are hitting.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.Yes, the ray was indeed colliding with some other objects. Thanks for pointing it out. Adding a layermask as suggested by  Thomas Hilbert in the comments below helped me resolve the issue. But the other problem of at times detecting platform instead of ground is still there even after adding shooting rays. @ Basile, its the first case.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/443013/checking-to-see-if-a-position-is-occupied-by-a-gam.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to add an offset to the Ray's starting position, to prevent problems when the Ray start from inside the searched object (which can happen if for example the Player rests on your platform, penetrating it by a tiny amount).

This adds an offset to the Ray to make sure to detect ground/platforms even if they are slightly penetrated:

```
private float distance = 0.5f;
private float offset = 0.5f;

void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    Ray footstepRay = new Ray(transform.position + (Vector3.up * offset), Vector3.down); // FIX: added an offset

    if(Physics.Raycast(footstepRay, out hit, distance + offset, LayerMask.GetMask("Ground", "Platform"))) // FIX: added a LayerMask
    {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Debug.Log ("Player is standing on the ground");
        }
        else if(hit.collider.tag == "Platform")
        {
            Debug.Log ("Player is standing on the platform");
        }
    }
}
```

The offset prevents missed detections when accidentally starting the Ray from inside the searched object.

Using an explicit LayerMask ensures you don't accidentally detect the Player or other unwanted objects.

Not detecting the platform when standing at its very edge is a different problem completely. What happens there is, your Ray, starting at the Player's center, simply passes by the platform once the center of your Player is no longer above the platform. You can fix that by sending multiple Rays at different positions, for example, on a circle around the Player's center.

This uses multiple Rays to improve ground/platform detection in edge cases (literally):

```
private float distance = 0.5f;
private float yOffset = 0.5f;
private float playerRadius = 0.3f;

void Update()
{
    string hitTag = DetectGround(Vector3.zero);
    if (hitTag != null)
    {
        OnFound(hitTag);
        return;
    }

    const int rays = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < rays; ++i)
    {
        float angle = (360.0f / rays) * i;
        Vector3 posOffset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up) * (Vector3.forward * playerRadius);

        hitTag = DetectGround(posOffset);
        if (hitTag != null)
        {
            OnFound(hitTag);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void OnFound(string tag)
{
    if(tag == "Ground")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player is standing on the ground");
    }
    else if(tag == "Platform")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player is standing on the platform");
    }
}

string DetectGround(Vector3 posOffset)
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray footstepRay = new Ray(transform.position + posOffset + (Vector3.up * yOffset), Vector3.down); // FIX: added an offset

    if(Physics.Raycast(footstepRay, out hit, distance + yOffset, LayerMask.GetMask("Ground", "Platform"))) // FIX: added a LayerMask
    {
        return hit.collider.tag;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Above code assumes you have Layers called "Ground" and "Platform" in addition to the tags. You can modify that as needed. The purpose of the LayerMask is to ensure that no objects except grounds and platforms are considered by the Raycast. You can either put them in separate Layers or into some kind of single "World" layer or whatever you choose, as long as the Player is not in the same Layer as grounds or platforms.

Edit: There may be situations where Ground sometimes is detected when standing on (the edge of) a Platform. This can happen if the `distance` field is set to a value greater than the minimum ground-to-platform distance. If that distance is constant, the issue can be fixed by adjusting the `distance` field accordingly. If the platforms are moving however, that approach will likely not work. In that case, using the object closest to the player should yield better results.

This example collects all the hits of all Rays and sorts them by distance. The closest hit is considered to be the desired result:

```
using System.Linq;

private float distance = 0.5f;
private float yOffset = 0.5f;
private float playerRadius = 0.3f;

void Update()
{
    List<RaycastHit> allHits = new List<RaycastHit>();
    DetectGround(allHits, Vector3.zero);

    const int rays = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < rays; ++i)
    {
        float angle = (360.0f / rays) * i;
        Vector3 posOffset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up) * (Vector3.forward * playerRadius);

        DetectGround(allHits, posOffset);
    }

    if (allHits.Any())
    {
        RaycastHit closestHit = allHits.OrderBy(hit => hit.distance).First();
        OnFound(closestHit.collider.tag);
    }
}

void OnFound(string tag)
{
    if(tag == "Ground")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player is standing on the ground");
    }
    else if(tag == "Platform")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player is standing on the platform");
    }
}

void DetectGround(List<RaycastHit> hits, Vector3 posOffset)
{
    Ray footstepRay = new Ray(transform.position + posOffset + (Vector3.up * yOffset), Vector3.down); // FIX: added an offset

    Debug.DrawLine(footstepRay.origin, footstepRay.origin + (footstepRay.direction * (distance + yOffset)), Color.red);
    hits.AddRange(Physics.RaycastAll(footstepRay, distance + yOffset, LayerMask.GetMask("Ground", "Platform")));
}
```

Note: This example does not require a LayerMask to work reliably. It may still make sense to use Layers to filter the considered objects for performance reasons if your game has many colliders in close proximity to the raycast.

Comment: *"Using an explicit LayerMask ensures you don't accidentally detect the Player or other unwanted objects."* The issue of player detecting itself is only a 2D raycast thing. It doesn't apply to 3D. Also, OP is filtering the detection with by checking the layer so "unwanted objects" is not the problem. The offset thing you talked about makes sense.

Comment: Well, it is certainly possible to detect the "source object" if there are faces that present their front face to the Ray. Feet are a likely example assuming the ray originates from the right spot (above the feet). Also, even if the result is filtered by tag it would still prevent detection of the desired Ground or Platform object, as `Raycast` only returns the first hit. If the Ground happens to be the second hit it won't be detected. If you really have to filter by tag, you have to use `RaycastAll` to make sure.

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks a lot for clarifying the concepts. It was really helpful. Adding the layermask helped me resolve the issue of ray colliding with unwanted objects that was happening earlier. I also tried shooting multiple rays as you suggested for the edge issue and the problem is resolved to some extent, but not completely. Now the incorrect detection of ground instead of platform is not happening, but the vice versa is happening at times. When standing on the platform, its working fine, but when moving from platform to ground (even if its not the edge), its detecting it as platform sometimes.

Comment: Yes that can happen depending on which Rays are tested first. You can either play with the `distance` parameter (making it smaller than the minimum platform<->ground distance might already fix your issue). You can also use `Physics.RaycastAll` to get all the hits for every Ray and collect them in a List. Once you have all hits for all the Rays you can sort them by distance and take the one closest to the player. That should pretty much be the result you're looking for.

Comment: If you are detecting platforms while standing on the ground, either the playerRadius is set too high (would detect platforms that are actually next to the player) or the yOffset is set too high (would detect platforms that are actually above the player). You can use `Debug.DrawLine` to show the raycasts in the Editor window, that should give you a good idea of what is going on (see my third code example).

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your patience. Really appreciate your help! I still have to try with your closestHit approach (FYI, since RaycastHit is a struct hence closestHit cannot be compared with null). My platform is fixed at the centre of the ground and is at some height. Player is never resting on the platform, its at some fixed height. A very annoying thing that is happening is that at the same position on the platform at times it works and sometimes it gives the tag as ground after this change: Ray footstepRay = new Ray(player.position + 0.04f * Vector3.down, Vector3.down); Any idea?

Comment: I fixed the struct-issue in the code sample, thanks for the info. Did you really use `Vector3.down` twice? It should be `Ray footstepRay = new Ray(player.position + 0.04f * Vector3.up, Vector3.down);`

Comment: @Thomas, Appreciate your help! I could not resolve the issue (probably something silly that I might be missing) but I have completely understood your explanation and I agree that whatever you have explained makes sense. I am accepting your answer. I am just learning VR, haven;t tried debugging rays earlier. Tried this time, but somehow could not see them. Found from net that we need to enable gizmos to be able to do that. Clicked on Gizmos button on the top right of the game/scene view. Anything else that is required? I am running the app on HTC Vive.

Comment: You will only see `Debug.DrawLine`s in the editor's "Scene" window (where you can create and move your GameObjects around), not the "Game" window. Gizmos don't need to be enabled to see those lines. If you can't find any, write a small sample script that draws a line somewhere obvious and try that for a start. Once you've found the lines things should become more obvious. Most important thing to be aware of is that Raycasts will only detect Colliders when they *enter* them, so a Raycast starting from inside a Collider will not detect said collider (in almost all cases).

Comment: Also note that the Lines are only visible during the frame they are drawn in, so make sure they are drawn every frame or it may be difficult to see them.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for clarifying. You have been of great help!